# Low camera FPS with OpenCV on Jetson Xavier

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, camera, python-3.6

I am currently running the program on a Jetson Xavier NX.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        breakc

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am using OpenCV 4.1.2 contrib, as well as the Orbbec Astra Embedded S as my camera. I am using Jetpack 4.4.

Not only am I getting low FPS (~5FPS), I am also getting a blue tinted screen.

Please help!

Comment: I worked on Jetson TX2 and the onboard camera is RGBA (alpha channel too). Can you try converting `if (frame.type() == CV_8UC4) {cvtColor(frame, frame, cv::COLOR_BGRA2RGB);}` and check? Also, try to get the FPS and then try to set it to higher value.

Comment: Forgot to mention, try gstreamer for testing if it works there, then you can try something like [this](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/camera-fps-too-low-on-xavier/139480/10) to feed the pipeline to opencv.